# parent container not taking content height when set to relative

Tags: html, css

I have,

HTML,

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS,

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;    
    border : 1px solid red;
    height: auto;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 895px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border : 1px solid yellow;
}
```

**Issue** : - Outer does not take complete height of inner content

**Expected** : - It should take complete height

### Note

I can not hard code outer height

I want a scrollbar on outer.

http://jsfiddle.net/sefkao23/

Comment: if the inner is in absolute, the outer doesn't take it into account to compute its height: this is the expected behaviour

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan any workaoutnd

Comment: @Pilot tell us why you need it to be absolute? Otherwise your only workaround is JS to put .outer's height manually based on .inner height.

Comment: remove position: absolute from inner, if not necessary. Otherwise explain in your question (not inside the comment) what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Hi now try to this way

**You just define your** `.outer` `class` `width` or `height` as like this

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
       height: 895px; 
    border : 1px solid red;
    width: 1200px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    
   
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border : 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>    
</div>
```